# Automatically checking checkbox after choose option from select - works only in FF

Tags: javascript

I have somethink like this, but it works on FF but don't want in chrome, opera or safari. I have no idea why... Do you know? How fix it?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>

<select name="visitData[client_id]"  class="input input-select">
    <option   onclick="$('#visit-paid').prop('checked', true);"    value="67"> true</option>
    <option   onclick="$('#visit-paid').prop('checked', true);"    value="77">true</option>
    <option   onclick="$('#visit-paid').prop('checked', false);"    value="42">false</option>
    <option   onclick="$('#visit-paid').prop('checked', true);"    value="14">true</option>
    <option   onclick="$('#visit-paid').prop('checked', true);"    value="50">true</option>
    <option   onclick="$('#visit-paid').prop('checked', false);"    value="26">false</option>
</select>
    <input type="checkbox" name="visitData[paid]" value="1" class="input input-checkbox" id="visit-paid"/>

<br/><input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an extra attribute for your options. If it's `true`, in this case there's an attribute named `data-check`

```
<select name="visitData[client_id]" class="input input-select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option data-check="true" value="67">foo</option>
    <option data-check="true"  value="77">foo</option>
    <option value="42">bar</option>
    <option data-check="true" value="14">foo</option>
    <option data-check="true" value="50">foo</option>
    <option value="26">bar</option>
</select>



$('.input-select').on('change', function () {
    var check = ($('option:selected', this).attr('data-check') ? true : false);
    $('#visit-paid').prop('checked', check);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ES7DP/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Code looks OK . Try something like below

```
         <select name="visitData[client_id]"  class="input input-select" id="dropDown">
           <option      value="67"> true</option>
         <option     value="77">true</option>
          <option     value="42">false</option>
         <option     value="14">true</option>
         <option      value="50">true</option>
       <option    value="26">false</option>
     </select>




 //jquery
         $(document).on('click','#dropDown option',function(){

                $('#visit-paid').prop('checked', $.trim($(this).text()));
       });
```

Comment: Ok, but of course in my code I have different text beetween  option :)... No true or false so I have to do it in different way

Comment: you can put data-* attribute in option tag for true or false

Comment: e.g. <option data-value="true" ><option> and then jquery would be

Comment: $('#visit-paid').prop('checked', $.trim($(this).attr('data-value')));

Comment: $('#visit-paid').prop('checked', $.trim($(this).text())); this will not work

Comment: try to put data-* attribute in option tag as mentioned previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
<select name="visitData[client_id]"  class="input input-select">
        <option  value="67"> true</option>
        <option  value="77">true</option>
        <option  value="42">false</option>
        <option  value="14">true</option>
        <option  value="50">true</option>
        <option  value="26">false</option>
    </select>


        <script>

        $(".input-select").change(function()
        {
          var t=$.trim($(".input-select :selected").text());
          $('#visit-paid').prop('checked',t.bool());
        })

        String.prototype.bool = function() 
        {
          return (/^true$/i).test(this);
        };
        </script>
```

Comment: The option text is not "true" or "false" in his code.

Comment: sorry i forgot to check that